# Editing files in a read-only directory in docker container

Tags: dockerfile, readonly

I would like to add some Core dump configuration to an Opensips docker container. At present, I am only generating a coredump file with the name "core" (which could be overwritten).

The changes I need to make are:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid     --> which generates "core.6645" for example
```

and

```
echo 'core.t.sigp' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern     --> This will have the core file contain the process name ( % e ), the timestamp ( % t ), the received signal ( % s ) and the pid file ( % p )
```

The problem is, the /proc/sys/kernel/ filesystem is Read-Only, so both attempts at editing files gets this error when building the image (I added the above commands to the Dockerfile):

```
/proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid': Read-only file system
```

Any ideas on how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, you need create your container with **--privileged**:

ex.:

```
docker run --privileged -i --name master --hostname k8s-master -d ubuntu:20.04
```